# Sugarcrm instance has no attribute 'module'

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to collect data from sugarcrm and have the following code:

```
import sugarcrm

sugarcrm_user = "user"
sugarcrm_pass = "pass"
sugarcrm_url  = "url/service/v4/rest.php"

sugarcrm_conn= None

try:
    sugarcrm_conn = sugarcrm.Sugarcrm(url = sugarcrm_url, username = sugarcrm_user, password = 
    sugarcrm_pass)
    accounts = sugarcrm_conn.module('Accounts')
except ValueError:
    print "cann't connect to " + sugarcrm_url
    exit(1)
```

The connect works fine, but when I try to use the sugarcrm object is says

> Sugarcrm instance has no attribute 'module'

Answer (score 0):

Using [this link](http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-python-rest-i-68) section **#1.b - Method 2: Using pure JSON** was a great alternative:

```
filtered_accounts = sugarcrm_conn.get_entry_list('Accounts', 'accounts.name like "%batman%"', 'accounts.name DESC', 0, ['name','date_entered','email1']) #here offset is 0
print filtered_accounts
for account in filtered_accounts['entry_list']:
    name_value_list = account['name_value_list']
    print "name=%s,email=%s" % (name_value_list['name']['value'],name_value_list['email1']['value'])
```